# Interpreting regression coefficient for categorical outcome variables

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, categorical-data, linear-model, regression-coefficients

I have a linear regression model, where the outcome variable `diagnosis` is a categorical variable representing a tumor being either "malignant" or "benign":

`lm(diagnosis ~ radius + perimeter + compactness + smoothness, ...)`

I'm not sure how to interpret the regression coefficients for the binary categorical variable here. For instance, the variable `smoothness` has a regression coefficient of $16.9805981$, how would we interpret this? Something like: ***a 1 unit increase in `smoothness.stderr` increases the probability of `diagnosis=1` (i.e. malignant) by 16.9805981?***

Comment: You should use logistic regression for 0-1 outcomes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146914/what-is-the-difference-between-linear-regression-and-logistic-regression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "diagnosis" is coded as either 0 or 1, then your interpretation is in the ballpark.  There are issues with causality, ceteris paribus, and estimates vs actual, but you have the right idea.

But the result is indeed strange, so I would guess that you have something like 0,100 instead of 0,1 for "diagnosis"; or that the "smoothness" variable has a very small sdev so that a one unit increase is out of bounds; or maybe that there is extreme multicollinearity, which might imply a one unit increase is out of bounds, ceteris paribus.

Or maybe there is some other mistake, like reading the output wrong.

Finally, you should use logistic regression here.